# Is there a way to force Webview to cache heavy files?

Tags: android, webview

It seems like Webview doesn't cache files which are a bit heavy. I've tried with JPG and PDF files around 10Mo and every time it loads it again. I have included :

```
webview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
webview.getSettings().setAppCachePath("/data/data/" + getPackageName() + "/cache");
webview.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
webview.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
```

But it only caches css, and javascript from what it seems.

As `webview.getSettings().setAppCacheMaxSize();` has been deprecated and that Webview deals by itself with the caching mechanism, I was wondering if there was trick to solve this issue (maybe downloading manually the file and store it locally, then, everytime the heavy file is called replace it by the local one ?).

Thanking you all in advance for your answer.